# Shen (神) character painted over a seal

Tags: seal

The same 神 character is painted over a seal on 2 different artworks:

- An early [landscape painting](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BA%94%E4%BB%A3%E5%8D%AB%E8%B4%A4%E9%AB%98%E5%A3%AB%E5%9B%BE/1054619?fromtitle=%E5%8D%AB%E8%B4%A4%E9%AB%98%E5%A3%AB%E5%9B%BE&fromid=10293285) (by Wei Xian/卫贤?):

  [image: seal_wei_xian]
- A [calligraphy](https://theme.npm.edu.tw/selection/Article.aspx?sNo=04001001&lang=2) by Wang Xizhi:

  [image: seal_wang_xizhi]

Painting over a seal seems rather rare to me. I guess this one is the seal from a collector, but I might be wrong. Do you know a particular reason why it has been painted? And does it have a special meaning (maybe a religious one)?

Edit: here's an attempt to make the seal readable:

[image]

Comment: It looks more like the seal was stamped over the character afterwards.

Comment: Right, it is obvious now you've said it. I can't read the seal script unfortunately...

Comment: the seal is "乾隆寶翰", his majesty seal of the fifth Emperor of qing dynasty: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qianlong_Emperor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

well, the emperor 乾隆 was a collector, he used four characters "神", "妙", "能" & "逸" to categorise artworks (calligraphy, or painting).

and then, he used his seal to chop on the artwork :(

Comment: Thanks 水巷孑蠻! I found an English explanation here thanks to your hint: http://theme.npm.edu.tw/exh102/qianlong/en/en02.html

Comment: great, you get it :)